# Can you create a custom view?

Tags: android, image, android-gridview, custom-view

I am trying to recreate a screen from one application (see picture). The problem I am facing is focused on the grid elements of the screen. Is it possible to create a custom view which is a combination of an image and a text view (like in the picture) or should I add the image view and text views separately in each row of the grid view?

[image: two muppets]

Comment: Create one layout for card and reuse it. It's such common use case.

Comment: yes it is possible check this link https://medium.com/@douglas.iacovelli/the-beauty-of-custom-views-and-how-to-do-it-79c7d78e2088

Comment: I see, will do some research on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

step 1 :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="134dp"
    android:layout_height="154dp"
    android:background="@drawable/grey_rounded_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        tools:src="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/caption"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="Caption of the Image"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#666"
        android:textSize="12sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

step 2

```
<declare-styleable name="BenefitView">
    <attr name="image" format="reference"/>
    <attr name="text" format="string"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

step 3

```
class BenefitView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): LinearLayout(context, attrs) {

    init {
        inflate(context, R.layout.benefit_view, this)

        val imageView: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.image)
        val textView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.caption)

        val attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.BenefitView)
        imageView.setImageDrawable(attributes.getDrawable(R.styleable.BenefitView_image))
        textView.text = attributes.getString(R.styleable.BenefitView_text)
        attributes.recycle()

    }
}
```

use :

```
<com.iacovelli.customview.BenefitView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:text="Apply and chat with our hosts"
      app:image="@drawable/first_image"
      android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"/>
```

Comment: Can you further explain the steps? From what I can get, step 1 is creating a new layout which will act as a card, step 3 is the class file for that card, but step 2 and 4 escape me.

Comment: https://medium.com/@douglas.iacovelli/the-beauty-of-custom-views-and-how-to-do-it-79c7d78e2088